Firearm ownership after voluntary mental health commitment as a minor?
I am now over the age of 18 and am looking to purchase a long gun for sport and skeet shooting.
As a minor, I was VOLUNTARILY committed, never by the court or a legal authority, to a ward. I cooperated and admitted myself.
I know you’re asked if you were “involuntarily held” on the background check. My answer is no, but who knows what the hospitals reported. It was definitely never court or police ordered. I have NEVER had a history of violence, so I know that’ll not be on record. I was quite unhappy as you would imagine to be in there but always released without issue and was never put in to a detention or a hold as far as I know.
This was long ago; I am a stable, functioning adult now and shot plenty as a kid, even took safety classes, so I’d really like to get back in to the hobby. I’ve obviously never been hospitalized in any fashion over 18. I only have traffic crimes on record (ran a yellow light 1x) and selling a vape to an undercover “minor” who had a fake ID — and a beard - once, which seems backwards, but it was just a ticket — so no criminal record at all.
I currently reside in OK if that helps. I know I can appeal with my doctor’s help if I get denied, but to be honest, I don’t want to risk a denial and pay a bunch of money to get the gun returned (purchasing it online and shipping it to FFL dealer).
Is there any way to get the background check in advance or to see if I’m “pre-qualified” like a credit check? I’d rather know in advance, get the appeal with my doctor and a lawyer done and then never have a history of a denial.
Thank you all for any help! I know it’s not a traditional question and it’s a sensitive topic, but I’d appreciate any insight. Shooting was a really important hobby to me growing up and a goal of mine is to join a gun club and compete, so this is pretty close to my heart.

Update: my mental health professional has confirmed that all of my hospitalizations as a minor were voluntary, I shouldn’t have an issue with the background check as he hasn’t tried to put any sort of hold on me and that he will write a petition if need be.

As written this seems like specific legal advice, which is off-topic here. However, the general question, 'does being voluntarily committed to ward prevent one from purchasing a firearm in the US' would be a legitimate question.

Please inquire with a lawyer specializing in firearms in your area. Many offer a free or low cost consultation in which they discuss the situation for you.

There's no way to pre-qualify for a NICS check since it must be for an actual sale with a make, model and serial number of the firearm, but if you have a friendly local FFL you can explain your situation and purchase a used firearm from them and immediately sell it back. Expect to pay a fee for their time and effort.

@MTA Incorrect. No model/serial information is input into NICS. Further, you do not need to buy a gun, NICS checks can be made for other purposes including pawning and rentals. Some states have a eligibility checking process (CA PFEC). Some other states require firearms purchase permits. Generally, they will run a NICS check as part of the issuance of the permit; part of the purpose is to allow more time to resolve a records issue. The permit replaces the time-of-sale NICS check. Finally, a NICS check is run when applying for a CCW permit, and many states accept a permit in lieu of NICS.

@user71659 For a local solution to the OP's situation, a NICS check in advance of an online purchase, an FFL must use ATF form 4473 and must fill in the boxes for make, model and serial number before allowing the OP to fill out the rest of the form. Whether the form is used for a purchase, a private transfer or a pawn redemption is immaterial, the data are required; no hypothetical NICS checks by an FFL are supported by NICS or by ATF recordkeeping requirements. Re "state dependent", absolutely true. Some states (e.g., NH) don't even require a NICS check for a CCW permit.

This is very state dependent.
Some states do have a process for pre-checking. For example, the California Personal Firearms Eligibility Check. You fill out the form and the California Department of Justice will check databases and determine your eligibility. Check with your state DOJ/AG.
Some states and cities require a firearms permit for purchase and/or possession. In that situation, determination of eligibility and a NICS check is generally done at the time of issuance of the permit. Part of the reason for a permit system is to allow more time to resolve records issues beyond the Federally-allowed 3 business day NICS delay.
